# fullstackcapapi.models.version.Version.DoesNotExist: Version matching query does not exist

Tags: python, reactjs, django, next.js

I'm making a public prayer journal full stack(for context, the version in the error is closer to Bible translation). Whenever I edit a verse and submit it, I get "fullstackcapapi.models.version.Version.DoesNotExist: Version matching query does not exist." on the backend and this on the frontend: "PUT http://localhost:8000/verses/2 500 (Internal Server Error)".

The lines these errors point to:
`fetch(`${dbUrl}/verses/${verseId}`,`
`verse.version_id = Version.objects.get(id=request.data["version_id"])`

Backend:

```
def update(self, request, pk):
        "Handle PUT requests for a single post"""
        verse = Verse.objects.get(pk=pk)
        verse.uid = User.objects.get(id=request.data["uid"])
        verse.verse = request.data["verse"]
        verse.version_id = Version.objects.get(id=request.data["version_id"])
        verse.content = request.data["content"]
        verse.save()
        
        serializer = VerseSerializer(verse)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Frontend:

```
const updateVerse = (user, verse, verseId) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const verseObj = {
    version_id: Number(verse.version_id.id),
    verse: verse.verse,
    content: verse.content,
    uid: user.id,
  };
  fetch(`${dbUrl}/verses/${verseId}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(verseObj),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  })
    .then((response) => resolve(response))
    .catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```

And also this in case it's needed:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (verseObj.id) {
      updateVerse(user, currentVerse, verseObj.id)
        .then(() => router.push('/'));
    } else {
      const payload = { ...currentVerse };
      createVerse(payload, user).then(setCurrentVerse(initialState));
    }
  };
```

I don't really know what to do here, any help is appreciated.